# Bing Maps AJAX Control, Version 6.3 - can't replace pin image for map birdivew

Tags: jquery, ajax, dictionary, bing, pushpin

I'm using the Bing Maps AJAX Control, Version 6.3 currently and all is working as expected apart from this...:

I'd like to replace the default pushpin icon with a custom one. I've succeeded doing this in default view by adding the following line of code to my map.js:

```
    $(".VEAPI_Pushpin").find('img').attr('src', '../App_Themes/Default/Images/pointer.gif');
```

I'm having difficulties with the birdseye view. It keeps displaying the default image for the pushpin...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

I replicated this same line of code on window.load() and this overwrote the class for birdseye style.